# Communicating in Wifi LAN, Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, wifi, lan

I have two devices 1 as a hotspot host other as a client connected.

Both are android devices.

I tried to doing it with tcp programming but was unable to do it.

Do anyone knows how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to do it with java sockets.

The thing that was actually confusing was the use of ip addresses.

I never was able to figure out,
How to assign ip address or how to get ip address of the wifi hotspot host.

So,
I Found a code through which I was able to scan all the connected devices to the hotspot and their respective ip addresses.

So I instantiated it from the host side...

Which I wanted to do from client side...

Calling ServerSocket on the Client
And connected to it from wifi hotspot host using Socket(ipAddr,port)

I still would like to do it as I wanted.

I didn't knew the core concepts of ip addresses and networking it is just the solution that i came up with the help of the internet and little bit of code that found here and there.